# How to get my facebook application user's other application list?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I am creating one facebook application which need to know our application user is using which other application..

I search on google for this type of things but fails..

If any one know please let me know, and first let me know is it possible or not.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I do not think it is possible. As other applications may not give the permission to your app. You think If u have an app and someone tries to get Info regarding it then You will obviously deny it

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, this cannot be done directly through their API due to privacy. Do you also control the other application? If so, when they authorize that one, I would store the user's info in a database. The other application could then query that database and find out if the user is using your other app.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, I want to know about user application which not connected with my applications like i want to know which game my user playing with his friends and how much he scored.